# Ref. request: Enumerating elements of Bruhat cells

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, symmetric-groups, coxeter-groups

Given a field $F$ and a natural number $n$, let $B$ be the group of lower triangular, invertible $n \times n$ matrices over $F$. Then
$$GL_n(F) = \biguplus_{\pi \in S_n} B \pi B,$$
where we embed the symmetric group $S_n$ into $GL_n(F)$ by use of permutation matrices; this is the so-called Bruhat decomposition (or at least a special case of it). Now the following seems to be well-known (I found it in *Donald Taylor: The Geometry of the Classical groups*, but I assume it can be found in many other books):

> Every element $A \in B \pi B$ has a unique representation as $A = b\pi u$ for $b \in B$ and $u \in U_{\pi}$, where $U_{\pi}$ is some subgroup of $B$ that depends on $\pi$.

Elements of $B$ can be easily enumerated, i.e. it is straight forward to give a bijection between $B$ and $$F^{{n \choose 2}} \times (F^*)^n.$$
Furthermore, $U_{\pi}$ can be viewed as an $F$-vector space of dimension $\ell(\pi)$, where $\ell(\cdot)$ is the Coxeter length on $S_n$. However, I haven't found a source yet that explicitly gives this vector space structure, it mostly comes out as a side result (sometimes only the size of $U_{\pi}$ in the finite case gets computed) or authors are only interested in geometrical results and not in the element-wise, combinatorial structure of the cells.

So my question is:

> Is there a known, easy to compute bijection between $U_{\pi}$ and $F^{\ell(\pi)}?$
>   Related to that: Is there a known, easy to compute bijection between $B \pi B$ and 
>   $$F^{{n \choose 2} + \ell(\pi)} \times (F^*)^n.$$

Comment: As I recall it, $U_\pi$ is by definition the set of upper triangular matrices $u$ with ones on the diagonal where $i<j$ and $u_{ij}\not=0$ implies $\pi(j)>\pi(i)$; in other words, all variable coefficients of $u$ are supported on the inversions of $\pi$. That makes $U_\pi\cong F^{l(\pi)}$ as obvious as it gets, doesn't it?

Comment: @Dirk: It's not clear what you mean about a unipotent group $U_\pi$ being a "vector space".    For example, what is the vector space structure for the full lower triangular unipotent group?    It's of course known that in terms of algebraic geometry, the group is always isomorphic to an affine space of dimension $\ell(\pi)$.   In particular, a bijection exists.